# PostgreSQL with Python

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I have a running and working database in SQLite but multiple users are writing to it in the same time and i seem to have concurrency problems, because of the database being locked. 
What do i need in order to create and access a PostgreSQL database in Python? Is there a way in which i dont install anything else than python libraries? I have a company laptop and would need 1XXXX approvals to install a third party software.

The setup is simple: The users go to the upload page on the site(built in django), uploads a xls file and the info gets extracted into a database(while being compared with info from inside the database). If 2 users try to upload files in the same time, i get database locked error.

Any help would be great, either to solve this SQLite problem or to get me started in Postgre if this should solve it. THX!

Comment: This could maybe of some help.. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZuLTGjcLUAhULMI8KHTaWC8UQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04&usg=AFQjCNEx7Scw_7tl2hJx4ESCHaL6JcShNg

Comment: You can use Docker for an easy setup of your postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not suitable for multiple user access since it is just a file acting as a database. To get the real power of DBMS you have to switch either MySQL or PostgreSQL which are officially supported by Django. Remember that PostgreSQL is preferred by Django for production use. Anyway you can use Oracle DB if you company already have it.

You need to setup `settings.py` in your project folder in order connect any database with Django as follows.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You may need to install relevant db driver to connect it with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Before committing to migrating to PostgreSQL, you may want to simply increase the busy timeout of your SQLite3 database and see if that produces acceptable results.